# How to take a textbox and print the contents in a url (MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view with a textbox and a button.  I want to take the textbox and take the contents of what a user types in and put it as a "Get" variable in the URL.  Does anyone have a simple example of this?
I want it to print into a url like this: /Profiles/Search?searchstring=hello

I am using razor built in mvc3 view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a strongly typed view, you could do:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchString)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Otherwise, with a weakly typed view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("searchstring")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```